# How to get the selected value from my kivy dropdown menu

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy

I have a dropdown menu in which I would like to know which value the user has selected so I can use it later in my program. This is my .kv code:

```
BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint_x: 1

            Button:
                pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                id: units_num_btn
                text: '0'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 44
                on_parent: drop_player_numbers_units.dismiss()
                on_release: drop_player_numbers_units.open(self)

            DropDown:
                id: drop_player_numbers_units
                on_select: units_num_btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
                on_select: app.return_player_numbers()

                Button:
                    id: units_num_btn_1
                    text: '1'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 35
                    on_release: drop_player_numbers_units.select('1')


                Button:
                    id: units_num_btn_2
                    text: '2'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 35
                    on_release: drop_player_numbers_units.select('2')
```

and so on.

My .py code is here:

```
class drop_content(DropDown):
    pass

class PlayerScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TheApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(PlayerScreen(name='player_setup'))
        sm.current = 'player_setup'

        return sm

def main():
    Builder.load_file('menu.kv')
    app = TheApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have previously used a function such as this:

```
#       .py example
def return_text(self):
        text = self.root.get_screen('screen').ids.specific_id.text
        print(text)
```

```
# .kv example

TextInput:
     id: input
     text: "2"
     on_text: app.return_text()
```

which did return text using a `Textinput` type in my .kv file. I know it doesn't work for the dropdown menu since the text is not inputted in the same way. Do you know how I would do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way that I think  is simpler than the current answer provided. This method uses that fact that the text on the button used to initiate the drop down changes as another button is selected. This is to show the user what they have selected. Since I want to know the text the user has selected from the drop down menu, and this is in fact the same thing that is updated on the initial button, I can just read the text from the button to obtatin my result like so:

(in .kv file)

```
<player_setup>
BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_x: 0.2
        pos_hint: {'x':.4, 'y':0}

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            id: tens_num_btn
            text: '0'
            size_hint_y: None
            # size_hint_x: 0.1
            height: 44
            on_parent: drop_player_numbers_tens.dismiss()
            on_release: drop_player_numbers_tens.open(self)

        DropDown:
            id: drop_player_numbers_tens
            on_select:
#######
                tens_num_btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])   
# this line here ^ is the one that re-formats the text of the button above to
#  the selected text

                app.return_player_numbers()
            max_height: 120
```

(.py file)

```
def return_player_numbers(self):

        player_number = self.root.get_screen('player_setup').ids.tens_num_btn.text
        return player_number
```

This also allows me to concatenate multiple dropdown results using a single function, however it is menu specific. In my case, this works better for me

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder







class TestScreen(Screen):

    def return_player_numbers(self,play_number):

        print('Test : ',play_number)



kv = '''



ScreenManager:

    TestScreen:



<TestScreen>:

    

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: 'horizontal'

        size_hint_x: 1



        Button:

            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

            id: units_num_btn

            text: '0'

            size_hint_y: None

            height: 44

            on_parent: drop_player_numbers_units.dismiss()

            on_release: drop_player_numbers_units.open(self)



        DropDown:

            id: drop_player_numbers_units

            on_select:

                units_num_btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

                app.root.current_screen.return_player_numbers(args[1])

                app.return_player_numbers(args[1])



            Button:

                id: units_num_btn_1

                text: '1'

                size_hint_y: None

                height: 35

                on_release: drop_player_numbers_units.select('1')





            Button:

                id: units_num_btn_2

                text: '2'

                size_hint_y: None

                height: 35

                on_release: drop_player_numbers_units.select('2')



'''

class TheApp(App):

    def return_player_numbers(self,play_number):

        print('App : ',play_number)

    def build(self):



        return Builder.load_string(kv)





if __name__ == '__main__':

    TheApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. What is the use of the line `app.root.current_screen.return_player_numbers(args[1])`. It seems to work without it?

Comment: I did it in two ways to make it clear

Comment: app.root.current_screen.return_player_numbers(args[1]) The function is called from the current screen  and app.return_player_numbers(args[1]) The function is called from app

Comment: is there a way to check the id of the dropdown that returns the function? so if I had 2 dropdowns and wanted to store each value as different elements in a list, and return that list in a single function, would that be possible?

Comment: something like
`if self.root.ids = drop_menu_1 :`
   `one = returned_value`
`elif self.root.ids = drop_menu_2:`
    `two = returned_value`
`return [one, two]`

Comment: Create two functions return_player_numbers1 and return_player_numbers2, the first call it from the first DropDown and the second from the second DropDown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248876/discussion-between-islam-abdelmoumen-and-max-davies).